# Can't parse customized results without using requests within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script using scrapy to fetch all the links connected to the name of different actors from imdb.com and then parse the first three of their movie links and finally scrape the name of `director` and `writer` of those movies. My script does it flawlessly if I stick to the current attempt. However, I've used `requests` module (which I don't want to) within `parse_results` method to get the customized output.

***[website address](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058011111/)***

What the script does (consider the first named link, as in `Robert De Niro`):

1. The script uses the above url and scrape the named link to parse the first three movie links from [here](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000134/?ref_=nmls_hd) located under the title `Filmography`.
2. Then it parses the name of `directors` and `writers` from [here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4075436/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1)

This is I've written so far (working one):

```
import scrapy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058011111/']

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        for name_links in soup.select(".mode-detail")[:10]:
            name = name_links.select_one("h3 > a").get_text(strip=True)
            item_link = response.urljoin(name_links.select_one("h3 > a").get("href"))
            yield scrapy.Request(item_link,meta={"name":name},callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self,response):
        name = response.meta.get("name")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        item_links = [response.urljoin(item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".filmo-category-section .filmo-row > b > a[href]")[:3]]
        result_list = [i for url in item_links for i in self.parse_results(url)]
        yield {"actor name":name,"associated name list":result_list}

    def parse_results(self,link):
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        try:
            director = soup.select_one("h4:contains('Director') ~ a").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception as e: director = ""
        try:
            writer = soup.select_one("h4:contains('Writer') ~ a").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception as e: writer = ""
        return director,writer


c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

})
c.crawl(ImdbSpider)
c.start()
```

Output the above script produces (desired ones):

```
{'actor name': 'Robert De Niro', 'associated name list': ['Jonathan Jakubowicz', 'Jonathan Jakubowicz', '', 'Anthony Thorne', 'Martin Scorsese', 'David Grann']}
{'actor name': 'Sidney Poitier', 'associated name list': ['Gregg Champion', 'Richard Leder', 'Gregg Champion', 'Sterling Anderson', 'Lloyd Kramer', 'Theodore Isaac Rubin']}
{'actor name': 'Daniel Day-Lewis', 'associated name list': ['Paul Thomas Anderson', 'Paul Thomas Anderson', 'Paul Thomas Anderson', 'Paul Thomas Anderson', 'Steven Spielberg', 'Tony Kushner']}
{'actor name': 'Humphrey Bogart', 'associated name list': ['', '', 'Mark Robson', 'Philip Yordan', 'William Wyler', 'Joseph Hayes']}
{'actor name': 'Gregory Peck', 'associated name list': ['', '', 'Arthur Penn', 'Tina Howe', 'Walter C. Miller', 'Peter Stone']}
{'actor name': 'Denzel Washington', 'associated name list': ['Joel Coen', 'Joel Coen', 'John Lee Hancock', 'John Lee Hancock', 'Antoine Fuqua', 'Richard Wenk']}
```

In the above approach I used `requests` module within `parse_results` method to get the desired output as I can't use `yield` within any list comprehension.

***How can let the script produce the exact output without using `requests`?***

Comment: I don't think there's a good way. Maybe forget about grouping them and do that in "item pipeline".

Comment: You are already using meta in one case. Why don’t you use the same approach? You would yield a request for the first url in the list, and keep the list with the remaining URLs in the request meta. The callback would store the relevant data from the response, and yield a request for the next URL from the list or, if the list of URLs in meta is already empty, yield the item with all aggregated data.

Comment: I would be very glad if you write an answer for this question as to how you meant really @Gallaecio. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @gallacio - That's an idea to get around using requests but it's still doing one at a time so it really defeats the purpose.

Comment: You are doing one at a time for an item, but if you have more items than configured concurrency that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can address this is using `Request.meta` to keep a list of pending URLs for an item across requests, and pop URLs from it.

As @pguardiario mentions, the drawback is that you are still only processing one request from that list at a time. However, if you have more items than configured concurrency, that should not be a problem.

This approach would look like this:

```py
def parse_items(self,response):
    # …
    if item_links:
        meta = {
            "actor name": name,
            "associated name list": [],
            "item_links": item_links,
        }
        yield Request(
            item_links.pop(),
            callback=self.parse_results,
            meta=meta
        )
    else:
        yield {"actor name": name}

def parse_results(self, response):
    # …
    response.meta["associated name list"].append((director, writer))
    if response.meta["item_links"]:
        yield Request(
            response.meta["item_links"].pop(),
            callback=self.parse_results,
            meta=response.meta
        )
    else:
        yield {
            "actor name": response.meta["actor name"],
            "associated name list": response.meta["associated name list"],
        }
```

Comment: Looks promising!! Get back to you once I'm done implementing it within the script. Thanks for your time @Gallaecio.

Comment: Yes, it works as intended. You made my day @Gallaecio. Thanks a trillion.