# Scrapy request priority forloop

Tags: python, scrapy

```
    for each in player_url:
        yield scrapy.Request(each, callback=self.player_data2, priority=1)
    yield scrapy.Request(match_data.get('table_url'), callback=self.parse_table_url)
```

This is not working

Without completing forloop the next request is called

Comment: Are you sure about this? because executing for loop first is expected behavior. Chances are that the player_url is empty.

Comment: @HNMN3 `player_url` is not empty, confirmed, also the `len` is fixed but loop does it random and then exeutes the next request

Comment: Okay, I got your problem.

Comment: If you want the out-of-loop request to only happen once all requests from the loop have been handled, you need to yield that request from the last callback executed for those loop requests. It’s not straightforward, you will need to keep track in a class variable about the number of responses received, and you will need to make sure you handle errbacks in case a request from the loop gets a bad response.

Comment: If you don’t need those loop requests to happen asynchronously, you could alternatively go with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59156705/939364

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating `scrapy.Request` with the same priority (priority 1) in the for loop. If you want the first request to be processed first then assign the different priorities.

Check below:

```
priority = -1
for each in player_url:
    yield scrapy.Request(each, callback=self.player_data2, priority=priority)
    priority -= 1 # so that next request gets lesser priority
yield scrapy.Request(match_data.get('table_url'), callback=self.parse_table_url, priority=priority) # Assiging priority to this also so that this gets executed at last
```

Negative numbers can be used to show lesser priority.
Hope this helps!

Comment: didn't work bro, loop exeuted 8 times, instead of 11

Comment: Yes, the loop needs to be executed 11 times before proceeding to the next request. There is always an error if it doesn't.

Comment: Great! Best of luck buddy!